# How to connect to MySQL running on host from docker for mac

Tags: mysql, docker

## What I want to do

- Set up a backend server inside a Docker for Mac container.
- Access MySQL from that server, which is running on a host.

## Things you can't do

- Connect to MySQL from Docker for Mac.

## Things I've tried

- Started a container using `host.docker.internal` as follows.

```
docker run --rm -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu:22.04 sh start.sh
```

The url for sending a request to MySQL is as follows

````
app@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/app_name?parseTime=true&charset=utf8mb4
```
````

Comment: the way it is written is kind of hard for me to follow.  but i will do something like use docker compose to stand up 2 containers, 1 for the Backend and 1 for MySql.  Then i would expose the Mysql 3306 port so I can access it on my host to verify with apps like DBeaver etc.   It sounds though that youre trying to set up the Docker Container (backend) to talk to the Host Mysql DB? Why not abstract from Host and put it on your own container?

Comment: In Docker, 127.0.0.1 almost always refers to the current container, not the host system or another container.  You need to change that; if `host.docker.internal` works then that will be the correct host name.

Answer (score 0):

```
app@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/app_name?parseTime=true&charset=utf8mb4
```

to

```
app@tcp(host.docker.internal:3306)/app_name?parseTime=true&charset=utf8mb4
```

then

```
docker run --rm -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu:22.04 sh start.sh
```